# Javascript Regex and getElementByID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to search for all elements in a web page with a certain regex pattern.

I'm failing to understand how to utilize Javascript's regex object for this task. My plan was to collect all elements with a jQuery selector

```
$('div[id*="Prefix_"]');
```

Then further match the element ID in the collection with this

```
var pattern = /Prefix_/ + [0 - 9]+ + /_Suffix$/;
//Then somehow match it. 
//If successful, modify the element in some way, then move onto next element.
```

An example ID would be "Prefix_25412_Suffix". Only the 5 digit number changes.

This looks terrible and probably doesn't work:

1) I'm not sure if I can store all of what jQuery's returned into a collection and then iterate through it. Is this possible?? If I could I could proceed with step two. But then...

2) What function would I be using for step 2? The regex examples all use String.match method. I don't believe something like element.id.match(); is valid?

Is there an elegant way to run through the elements identified with a specific regex and work with them?
Something in the vein of C#

> foreach (element e in
>   ElementsCollectedFromIDRegexMatch) { //do stuff }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the "filter" function:

```
$('div[id*=Prefix_]').filter(function() {
  return /^Prefix_\d+_Suffix$/.test(this.id);
}).each(function() {
  // whatever you need to do here
  // "this" will refer to each element to be processed
});
```

Using what jQuery returns as a collection and iterating through it is, in fact, the fundamental point of the whole library, so **yes** you can do that.

*edit* — a comment makes me realize that the initial selector with the "id" test is probably not useful; you could just operate on all the `<div>` elements on the page to start with, and let your own filtering pluck out the ones you really want.

Comment: This will work, but is quite a bit slower than just running the match inside the each, since you need to do two iterations that both start new callstacks for each step...

Comment: I don't know that "quite a bit slower" is accurate.  A little slower, maybe, but not "quite a bit".  Actually the biggest speedup would be to quit doing the "id" test in the first selector; it's redundant and Sizzle is going to have to load up all the `<div>` elements on the page anyway.

Comment: @Pointy: Sizzle uses native `querySelectorAll()` where supported, so it should be faster than iterating over a very large number of `<div>` elements.  Also, it seems to me that attribute-starts-with (`^=`) is more appropriate here.  It might even be possible that `div[id^=Prefix_][id$=_Suffix]` would eliminate the need for filter and the regex altogether.

Comment: @Andy well yes that's a good point - I didn't spend much time thinking about the specifics of this one because the OP seemed basically in the dark about `.filter()` and how to use jQuery objects in general, so this was an opportunity to explain that stuff.

Comment: @Pointy: indeed :-) +1 for that.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! The subsequent explanations on this one are also very helpful. div[id^=Prefix_][id$=_Suffix] looks like a neat trick, and I'll have to try that out to see if it really works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter function. i.e:

```
$('div[id*="Prefix_"]').filter(function(){
 return this.id.match(/Prefix_\d+_Suffix/);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$('div[id*="Prefix_"]').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('id').search(/do your regex here/) != -1) {
   //change the dom element here
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the filter method, to do something like this...

```
var pattern = /Prefix_/ + [0 - 9]+ + /_Suffix$/;
$('div[id*="Prefix_"]').filter(function(index)
    {
        return $(this).attr("id").search(pattern) != -1;
    }
);
```

... and return a jQuery collection that contains all (if any) of the elements which match your spec.

Can't be sure of the exact syntax, off the top of my head, but this should at least point you in the right direction